# Windows Credentials login in web app

Tags: windows, web-applications, single-sign-on

Is there a way to login to a web application using one's windows credentials? Note that I'm expecting to do this in a promptless way i.e if the user selects "login using your windows credentials" it won't ask for them the *first time only* or anything similar.

I've read some things regarding `NTLM` and `Kerberos` and `Negotiate` but I got confused since they seem different to me but sources say Kerberos is the successor of NTLM and should be favored over it however people still use NTLM (version 2) for some reason.

I'd like to have some basic understanding of what is expected to work and what isn't before I start getting in deep into a documentation.

Comment: I'm not too sure if you are asking about **Single Sign-On** (SSO) -- i.e. the web browser should fetch the Active Directory credentials from the Windows LSA session cache *(provided the user uses an AD account)* and present these credentials *(a kerberos ticket, or faling that an NTLM token)* to the web server using SPNego protocol -- or about **impersonation** -- i.e. the web server should not just verify the credentials, but `doAs` some actions on behalf of the client using these credentials *(provided the Kerberos ticket is forwardable and some Microsoft "CanDelegate" flags are set)*

Comment: The client simply wants to have their users not have to sign up to the app and simply use their already existing windows credentials (that exist in AD) to sign into our **web app**. Just like one would do in a desktop application but this time we're talking about an application running in the browser through html5

Comment: Some hints about... why did Microsoft finally implement Kerberos *(with some specific extensions)* in AD as the standard mode of authentication, demoting NTLM? because NTLM was just not good enough; why did Microsoft promote SPNego? To make things easier for transitioning to Kerberos  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPNEGO and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953888/does-server-decide-what-authentication-method-is-to-be-followed/12958362#12958362

Comment: ...  >> why is NTLM still used in practice? because Kerberos is a VERY paranoid protocol, which requires careful configuration on both server and client side (canonical DNS names, one SPN per service/server -- use of load balancers requires hacks--, no clock skew, and some more stuff that AD and SSPI takes care of automatically but you have to handle yourself with Java and/or raw GSSAPI) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936243/sso-authentication-response-is-always-ntlm for example

Comment: So from what I'm reading, NTLMv2 is the way to go since it is the only protocol that will also enable the use of the pre-existing and hashed windows credentials that the user used to login right?